# import of geolib doesn't work in Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, node-modules, ember-cli

Trying to import Geolib from npm by:

```
npm install geolib --save
```

which generates in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.8.8",
    "ember-cli": "~2.18.2",
    "ember-cli-less": "3.0.1",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1"
  },
```

then in my test.js component:

```
import { getDistance } from 'geolib';
```

But ( yes, there is but ) when i access a page, it generates error:

```
loader.js:228 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `geolib` imported from `wash-app-dashboard/components/test`
    at missingModule (loader.js:228)
    at findModule (loader.js:239)
    at Module.findDeps (loader.js:173)
    at findModule (loader.js:243)
    at requireModule (loader.js:26)
    at Class._extractDefaultExport (index.js:389)
    at Class.resolveOther (index.js:109)
    at Class.superWrapper [as resolveOther] (ember-utils.js:418)
    at Class.resolve (resolver.js:133)
    at _resolve (container.js:886)
```

Something wrong with my settings, or what ? Cant find any solution but comment out the code.

Edit: 
I know, i've got an old project to work on in my hand. Currently upgrading from 2.4 ember to 2.18 ( then to latest ember ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have `"ember-cli": "~2.18.2",` installed. That is a pretty old `ember-cli` version. Back then `ember-auto-import` was not part of the default blueprint.

So do you have `ember-auto-import` installed? It is what basically makes imports to *just work*.

Comment: Holy moly guacamole, it worked, thanks ;) Only if i haven't spend 2 days search a google and write here right away.